# Nvidia driver 390 broken dependencies install preventing uninstall or new install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

I accidentally broke my nvidia driver 390 when trying to upgrade to 440. I don't remember exactly what I did, but it involved sudo writing in the bash.rc and following some online help. I would really like to not have to reinstall Ubuntu b/c dual-booting Windows 10.

Ubuntu 18.04

nvcc --version returns: `Cuda 9.2`

nvidia-smi returns: `command not found...`

But now, I cannot uninstall cuda or nvidia driver completely (I've tried purge nvidia/cuda and run cuda.pl uninstall file and some other regular techniques). I also cannot install any new drivers manually, with auto install, or through the software interface.

On a very basic command like sudo apt-get update or sudo apt -f install, I get the following error.

```
$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390
  libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386
  nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390
  nvidia-kernel-source-390
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-390
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-390
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/74.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 308 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 260157 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-390_390.116-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-390 (390.116-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-390_390.116-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/sbin/create-uvm-dev-node', which is also in package nvidia-kernel-common-390 390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-390_390.116-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And so then I...

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcuda1-390 : Depends: nvidia-390 (>= 390.116) but it is not installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-390 : Depends: nvidia-390 (>= 390.116) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to directly install nvidia-390, and delete the two files it says have unmet dependency and  keep cycling to this error.

Comment: Did you accidentally mess up your path while editing the .bashrc file or maybe the .bash_profile? Are you trying to reinstall the video driver while the desktop environment is being used or the video driver has already been loaded?

Comment: @Gordster Yes, I probably messed up the path. And I am trying to reinstall why logged in and on the terminal. The graphics are all wonky.

Comment: The key is, did you boot into single user mode? Make sure you do that before re-installing the video driver. Have your installation packages downloaded so you can boot into single user mode and try again. I had this issue once and it came down to me completely removing the video driver and cuda files, then rebooting, then installing the video driver from single user mode (unpacking only the files needed for my needs), then reinstalling the cuda package

Comment: This helped! I went to recovery mode and used dpkg clean. Then reinstalled all the stuff. Thank you!

Comment: @Yume Glad to hear that did it for you! I created an answer based off our comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue once. To fix it I had to reboot into single user mode, uninstall all of the old packages related to the nvidia driver and cuda, and then reinstall.

1. Download packages from the nvidia site
2. Reboot into single user mode. This can be achieved various ways but it involves rebooting, clicking the letter <kbd>e</kbd> at the grub menu, and then editing the boot parameters. In Ubuntu 16 this required adding the word `single` at the end of the line that start with "linux" and ends with "ro". You may have to check what your version of Ubuntu requires
3. Attempt to uninstall cuda packages and nvidia drivers from the system. You mentioned using dpkg clean for each of them. (Perfect!)
4. Go to downloaded packages and reinstall each **starting** with the nvidia video driver.
5. I recommend rebooting the system, and then installing the cuda package.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution :

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Unlock the dpkg – (message /var/lib/dpkg/lock)

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock.

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Now you can Install Nvidia-390 :

First, detect the model of your nvidia graphic card and the recommended driver. To do so execute:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001180sv00001458sd0000353Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

If you agree with the recommendation feel free to use ubuntu-drivers command again to install all recommended drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

sudo apt install nvidia-390

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Once the installation is concluded, reboot your system and you are done.

Automatic Install using PPA repository to install Nvidia Beta drivers

Using graphics-drivers PPA repository allows us to install bleeding edge Nvidia beta drivers at the risk of unstable system.

To proceed first add the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa repository into your system :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update
```

Next, identify your graphic card model and recommended driver:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001043sd000085ABbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

And Now Install The Desired driver which is nvidia-390 sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

```
sudo apt install nvidia-390

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Once done, reboot your system.